# SQL-Server performance metrics: What exactly is Lock Waits/Sec (or: Why is it that unrealistically high?)

Tags: sql-server

I have a production SQL-Server, which seems to have increasing numbers of request taking extremely long (median response time is low, average response time is growing steadily). Therefore I started monitoring internal stats like the "lock waits per second".

The **production instance returns nearly 2.000.000 Lock Waits/Sec**, the **test instance only ~3.000 Lock Waits/Sec**. (This discrepancy is of course not unexpected, since the production instance has all the load, the test instance only a few requests of devs testing the new version of the application.)

Lock Waits/Sec is defined by Microsoft as "**Number of lock requests per second that required the caller to wait.**"

This definition doesn't help me at all though, how could there be 2 million lock waits per second?? There are no even 2 million DB-requests at all, by far? Also this number fluctuates only by single digits over periods of time with very different load; if it is per second, it should move much, much more, shouldn't it?

Therefore my question: **What exactly does Lock Waits/Sec stand for, and how do I have to interpret the numbers above?**

Comment: How do you look at the value? If you use sys.dm_os_performance_counters, then it is an accumulated value (the "raw" value) so it will forever increase. So you would have to calculate the "per sec" value. Or, use the windows Perfmon application, which does this for you.

Comment: Yes, I look at sys.dm_os_performance_counters. That value being an accumulated value makes much, much more sense. My confusion was rooted in the fact that I initially used Metricbeat with the MSSQL module to monitor the data, which tagged that data as per second.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name "Lock Waits/Sec" is terribly misleading.

When you read this counter from `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`, it is a cumulative value that is reset when the instance is restarted.  Note that this is true of many (or maybe all?) of the "per second" counters here.

If you view it in Perfmon.exe, though, that application does the work of taking diffs and showing a "per second" view of the value.

In your case, 2 million lock waits over the entire uptime of the server might be pretty innocuous.  Of course, a lot of that probably depends on how *long* things waited on the locks, so this metric won't help you much in isolation.

To your broader issue, if you want to get a sense of what's going on with this server, running [`sp_BlitzFirst`](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit#sp_blitzfirst-real-time-performance-advice) is a good place to start.  It will take a 5 second sample of a number of performance-related metrics (including perfmon counters), and give you a summary of the good, the bad, and the ugly.